# php mysqli bind_param Wrong parameter count

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

There's a number of questions on this that are answered here but I cant find what is wrong with mine.

DB class that uses mysqli which is stored as a property. The prepare, bind and execute are triggered with the magic call methods:

```
public static function __callStatic($name, $arg)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($arg);
    echo '</pre>';
    if($name == 'Prepare'){
        self::$Stmt = self::$mysqli->prepare(implode(', ', $arg));
        $return = self::$Stmt;
    }elseif($name == 'Bind')
        $return = self::$Stmt->bind_param(implode(', ', $arg));
    elseif($name == 'Execute')
        $return = self::$Stmt->execute();
    else
        $return = self::$mysqli->$name(implode(', ', $arg));
    if(!self::GetErr())
        return $return;
}
```

Also I have a class that generates SQL statements. This is the ouput used in the prepare statement:

```
INSERT INTO account (UName, FName, LName, Email, Password, RecQuestion, RecAnswer, Admin) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Here is the code:

```
DB::Prepare(SQL::Table('account')->Insert([
    'UName' => '?',
    'FName' => '?',
    'LName' => '?',
    'Email' => '?',
    'Password' => '?',
    'RecQuestion' => '?',
    'RecAnswer' => '?',
    'Admin' => '?'
]));
DB::Bind('sssssssi', $userName, $fName, $lName, $email, $password, $recQ, $recA, $admin);
DB::Execute();
```

As I can see there are 8 types and 8 values to go with it...

also here is the output of `var_dump($arg)` for when DB::Bind is called

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "sssssssi"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "user"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "first"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "last"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "email@email.com"
  [5]=>
  string(64) "$2a$10$Tw4eOkUYA6SX8WP8XJfKZeFfOM9htVRJyP0d1iYlka0jNCV/qPGzazakT"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "recover"
  [7]=>
  string(64) "$2a$10$LrfK2EdkRi6pPdx1tUtPWe8p24T8ISdQHYhW0N06RjbvCrU4Flqiie4jU"
  [8]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: `DB::Bind('sssssssi', $userName, $fName, $lName, $email, $password, $recQ, $recA, $admin);` there are 9. Do you really need this `'sssssssi'?

Comment: yes that's how it should be? the first is the 8 types and then the 8 values. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: last time I checked. 1) $userName, 2) $fName, 3) $lName, 4) $email, 5) $password, 6) $recQ, 7) $recA, 8) $admin wheres the 9th value?

Comment: -_- look at the documentation. 'sssssssi' is a required paramater for the column types. s=string and i=int;

Comment: Try removing the quotes from around the question marks.

Comment: there are no quotes around them in the SQL statement. they are only in the argument because they are passed as a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`implode(', ', $arg)` returns a single string so it was only getting one parameter. The proper way to go about this is using `call_user_func_array();`

However its not as obvious as it may seem. `bind_param()` expects the arguements to be passed by reference and not by value. `__callStatic($name, $arg)` has an array of values and not references so a local copy with references to these values is needed.

**Solution:**

```
elseif($name == 'Bind'){
    foreach($arg as &$v)
        $Arg[] = &$v;
    $return = call_user_func_array(array(self::$Stmt, 'bind_param'), $Arg);
}
```